# R, install.packages('devtools') bug

Tags: r, package, devtools, install.packages

I can't seem to install devtools. I always get this message (at the end):

```
  * installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
  ** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  checking for curl-config... no
  Cannot find curl-config
  ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
  * removing ‘/home/vapri/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RCurl’
  Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘RCurl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
  * removing ‘/home/vapri/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/httr’
  Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘RCurl’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
  * removing ‘/home/vapri/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/devtools’
  Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpqLDAb0/downloaded_packages’
```

Can someone tell me whats up?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04, some research seems to imply that may be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look more closely:

```
 checking for curl-config... no
  Cannot find curl-config
```

You need the `curl-config` script.  In general, you want a package `libcurl*-dev` or alike, and the aming may vary between distros.  On the system on which I type this:

```
edd@max:~$ dpkg -S `which curl-config`
libcurl4-nss-dev: /usr/bin/curl-config
edd@max:~$
```

but there is also an alternate `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` which I use on some other systems, as well as `libcurl4-openssl-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Helped me.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```